# What can we say about $Q$ given $Q=P+\frac{1}{2}I$ where $P \in M_n \left(\mathbb{Z}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Let $P$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with integral entries and $Q=P+\frac{1}{2}I$, where $I$ denotes the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Then what can you say about $Q$.

Is it Idempotent?

Is it Invertible?

Is it Nilpotent?

Is it Unipotent?

According to me It is not necessary that it is Idempotent, Nilpotent, Unipotent.

For a counter example take the diagonal matrix $B=\left( b_{ij}\right)$ with $b_{ii}=i$.

I claim that it is invertible.

Consider the matrix $2Q=2P+I$. Reduce each entry modulo 2. We get $I$ whose determinant is $1$ hence determinant of $2Q$ must be odd. Hence $2Q$ is invertible and hence $Q$ is invertible.

Is this method correct?
Do you have any other better method?

Comment: Logic seems fine to me. Don't need a better method. | But note also that not only is it *not necessarily* idempotent, nilpotent, unipotent, but it is *necessarily not* idempotent, nilpotent, unipotent. That is, you can prove $Q$ can *never* be either of those three things, not only give an example where it isn't. Using almost the same logic. Can you see how? | Note moreover that $Q$ is invertible in $M_n(\Bbb Q)$, but its inverse is not necessarily inside $M_n(\Bbb Z)$ (although it *could* be).

Comment: @runway44 That's too Informative. Thank You, I will try to prove your claims!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to get invertibility of $Q$ is as follows:

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $P$, then $\lambda+\frac{1}{2}$ will be an eigenvalue of $Q$. We will show that $\lambda \neq -\frac{1}{2}$.

Consider the characteristic polynomial of $P$ (namely $\det(P-\lambda I)$). This is a monic polynomial with integer coefficients, so by the rational root theorem, all it's **rational** roots must be integers. Thus $\lambda$ cannot be $-1/2$, hence $Q$ does not have $0$ as an eigenvalue. This means $Q$ is invertible.